# Background image for the whole page

Tags: html, css, image

I want the picture to be the background for the whole page.

Another problem is that with the no-repeat property the photo disappears

Could someone write background properties to set?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    * {
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    body {
      width: 100%;
      height: 300vh;
    }
    
    body::after {
      content: '';
      background-image: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d0/Background-clouds.jpg');
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      min-width: 100%;
      min-height: 100%;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the background repeat property, add the `background-size: cover;` property.

Check the css rule below.

```css
body::after {
  content: '';
  background-image: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d0/Background-clouds.jpg');
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Can't some of the other parameters be removed now?

Comment: @Daniel could you select it as right answer, if this solves your issue? :) Happy coding

Comment: @AryanTwanju Sure :)

Answer (score 0):

Added `no-repeat` property as well and this works for responsive page as well no need to make the property `fixed`.

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}

.backgroundImg {
  background-image: url("http://placekitten.com/301/301");
  height: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="backgroundImg"></div>
</body>
```